# Pod-like structure for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I started using Ember.js a couple of days ago. There are two ways how someone can organize models, controllers, routes, etc:

1. conventional folders like `models/`, `controllers/`, ...
2. or, which I would prefer, a folder structure Ember.js calls Pods:
   `user/model.js`, `user/controller.js`, etc.

I'm curious if it is possible to use a similar structure in Rails as it would greatly improve coding performance and should increase maintainability *(I guess)*.

So what does it take to tell Rails to look for models, controllers, etc. in other directories than it is used to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few articles and forum discussions on this topic online with various approaches. You can simply reorganize your models and controllers by feature as described [here](https://www.belighted.com/blog/organize-rails-files-by-topic) if you're prepared for some configuration.

The most complete approach seems to be the book [Component-Based Rails Applications](https://leanpub.com/cbra) with a companion site [Component-Based Rails Application Resources](http://cbra.info/) from Stephen Hageman, Ryan Platte, Benjamin Smith and Enrico Teotti.

The blog post [A component based Rails architecture primer](http://teotti.com/component-based-rails-architecture-primer/) from Teotti provides a decent introduction, among the [numerous others](http://teotti.com/topics/component-based-rails-architecture/) he has posted. Basically you package your application up as gems using Rails engines. When [someone suggested a modular Rails in a Github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11607), the official response was to use engines.

I know simply providing links here is not generally recommended, but I'm wary of duplicating their content in a manner which is less clear.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you will see a lot in Rails is "Convention over Configuration".  The Convention in Rails is to have your Controllers in `/app/controllers/`, Models is `app/models/`, and Views is `app/views/`.

I've not see any Rails apps configured the way that you described, but it may be best for your purposes to develop the "Rails way" from the start.